# Header set the JWT token to xxx.yyy.zzz but the AspNet Core 2 REST API still gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm making a request that comes back as status code 401 Unauthorized. Checking the headers provided, it seems that the three hashes of *Authorization* header are correct. So I'm getting the sense that the validation is improperly set up.

I configured the services like this (and, of course, also used the authentication).

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UnbreakableCode"));
services.AddCors(...);
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(_ =>
  {
    _.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = key
    };
  });
services.AddMvc();
...
```

I have no idea how to diagnose it further and googling leads to a lot of hits but very little such I recognize as relevant. So I'm stuck there.

What should I look for?

Comment: Check the app logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting an issuer?

Comment: @Tratcher And an expected audience? :)